# ASP.net SQL Count method

Tags: asp.net, sql, authentication

I'm trying to make an login page.

I have a table for my users which have four columns.

id username password admin

I have one post but i cant log in. Here's my code:

```
    try
    {


        string strcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blogCS"].ToString();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = strcon;
        myConnection.Open();

        string strSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=' " + txtUsername + "' AND password='";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql, myConnection); 
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        myConnection.Close();

        if (count == 1)
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        else
            lblStatus.Text = Convert.ToString(count);

    }

    catch (Exception k)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = k.Message;
    }
```

Comment: What does it do for `txtUsername = "'; DROP TABLE users--"`? Seriously--please use parameterized queries. Stop now and add that, then come back to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is refined Code :

```
    try
    {


        string strcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blogCS"].ToString();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = strcon;
        myConnection.Open();

        string strSql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username=' " + txtUsername + "' AND password='" + txtPassword + "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql, myConnection); 
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        myConnection.Close();

        if (count == 1)
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        else
            lblStatus.Text = Convert.ToString(count);

    }

    catch (Exception k)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = k.Message;
    }
```

Comment: and is your table is filled with any data ??

Comment: put a breakpoint around, take a query and run it individually, see what comes up, if it also gives zero

Comment: if it also gives zero then there must be some extra white space around your variable or in databse, else caseing ]

Comment: yes it's correct and i added txtPassword.Text instead of txtPassword but still no diffrence.

and i insert the data myself through a form

Comment: I think i'm gonna kill myself... it was a white space -.-

Comment: lol, i had also suffered from that, lot of time, so i always use Trim everywhere, for insert or Select.

Comment: May I also suggest using a parameterized query so that you avoid some sketchy SQL injection attack vectors.

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=' " + txtUsername + "' AND password='";
```

Pass Password

Comment: But strange thing is that your query is working because you are passing txtUsername (textbox control) instead of txtUsername.Text (text inside textbox)

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem your answer is incomplete and incorrect

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Michael. I thought s/he can figure out the rest.